# How to create new column and calculate median in data.table when using a subset of data

Tags: r, data.table

Hi I have a data like this:

```
  date    type    data
198101       1     0.1
198101       1     0.3
198101       2     0.5
198102       1     1.2
198102       1     0.9
198102       2     0.7
198102       2     0.3
```

I would like to create a new column to show the median each month according to criteria when type == 1.

The result I would like to be is like this

```
  date    type    data    P50
198101       1     0.1    0.2
198101       1     0.3    0.2
198101       2     0.5    0.2
198102       1     1.2   1.05
198102       1     0.9   1.05
198102       2     0.7   1.05
198102       2     0.3   1.05
```

currently I do it this way, lets call the above data.table as dt

```
dt.median = dt[type == 1]
dt.median = dt.median[, .(P50 = median(data)), by=.(date)]
```

Then merge it back into the original dt

```
dt = dt[dt.median, nomatch = 0, by=.(date)]
```

Is there a quicker way to do this using .SD or .SDcol? I want to practice using .SD but just cannot figure it out with maybe one line of code?

What I could think of is currently

```
dt[, P50 := * .SD[type == 1] ...  * , by =.(date)]
```

but then I dont know what the syntax to put in to calculate median * .SD[type == 1] ... *,

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just index the data values within groups using a logical vector and assign with the data.table special assignment operator, `:=`

```
> dt[ , P50 := median(data[type==1]), by=.(date)]
> dt
     date type data  P50
1: 198101    1  0.1 0.20
2: 198101    1  0.3 0.20
3: 198101    2  0.5 0.20
4: 198102    1  1.2 1.05
5: 198102    1  0.9 1.05
6: 198102    2  0.7 1.05
7: 198102    2  0.3 1.05
```

Comment: Why you can name data as like this? I thought something before the brackets [ ... ]  must be the datatable name or .SD?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The `dt` is "before" the "[". In the j portion of arguments to `[.data.table` the column names can be used "nakedly". It's one of the distinguishing features of data.table objects. You almost never use the data.table name inside j-expression

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, I thought before the bracket must be the name of the datatable "dt[".  What you are saying is in the j portion of datatable syntax, we can name the column and condition according to another column? In this case data[type == 1]

Comment: R's evaluation mechanism will look inside the expression `data[type==1]` and first evaluate the `type==1` and return a logical vector value which will then get used by `[.default` to choose only those `data`-items for further processing by `median`. The data.table evaluation environment is expanded beyond the usual scope to include column names.

Comment: @Satish: I have no idea what that question really means. The median of 1.2 and 0.9 is 1.05 and there are no 0 values. Perhaps you were asking what happened to the FALSE results in the type==1 expression? FALSE is coerced to 0 when needed but used as an index it really means "omit". If you have your own separate question you should ask it. I shouldn't need to explain what's going wrong with your code in a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

From base R

```
v=dt$data
v[dt$type!=1]=NA
ave(v,dt$date,FUN=function(x) median(x,na.rm=T))
[1] 0.20 0.20 0.20 1.05 1.05 1.05 1.05
```